# What are the units of velocity in Google Location History JSONs?

Tags: google-maps, google

I have downloaded and used different code to visualize the data. Some of the code works with speed as it is available in the JSON files downloaded using Google Takeout. The speeds seem to be too slow to be in km per hour.

I have found no documentation on the topic. I filed a google help ticket with no answer. Aside from this, everything works great, but I need this information to be able to interpret my results.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is meters per second.

Comment: FYI the [wiki page](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) for Velocity points that out. I think major API's generally stick to [SI Base Units](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit).